# Run ktor test using `testApplication` without a client call

Tags: kotlin, ktor

Is it possible to write a ktor test without any client call? We have a ktor kafka consumer service that executes http calls. The shape of our test is:

```
startAndConfigureWiremock()


testApplication{
  application{
    changeConfiguration()
  }
  sendKafkaMessage()
  verifyExternalCall()
}
```

but the tests with any client calls do not work. Test code `verifyExternalCall()` is executed before the service is up and blocks the startup without any `testBlocking`.

When we try to add parallelism like GlobalScope.launch it runs the application, but it just starts and stops.

Looks like testApplication needs a client call to work at all and even ktor test relay on it: https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/blob/8b784f45a6339728ce7181498a5854b29bf9d2a5/ktor-server/ktor-server-core/jvmAndNix/test/io/ktor/server/application/HooksTest.kt#L81

Comment: Yes, a test server starts only when a client's request is made. In Ktor 2.2.0, there will be the ability to start a test server manually https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-4819

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer you are looking for but...

This definately looks like the incorrect place and method for performing this test.

Ktor is for building web APIs, it is for dealing with things like routing and serialisation. Why are you testing if an internal service is being started and is polling kafka for messages? This has nothing to do with ktor.

If you really want to do an integration test on this service rather:

- do not start ktor
- start kafka
- start your Kafka polling service
- send your message
- do your verification

If you really want to check that your kafka service is started by your ktor application just do a verification that some "startKafkaConsumer" function was called in your start up. This should most likely be done on some injected mock of your consuming service.

Comment: I have to disagree here. Ktor documentation says: "Ktor is a framework to easily build connected applications – web applications, HTTP services, mobile and browser applications". Limiting Ktor to web APIs is an oversimplification. I agree that most modern services will have some kind of endpoints to integrate with container orchestration systems etc. Ktor is not tied to HTTP and it this kind of testing approach works in 1.6 or even existing 2.x using the deprecated `withTestApplication` method.

Comment: The style of the test is a different story. In the project I am talking about, we use an integration testing style when you prove that an application is correctly wired and performs as expected. It probably could be described as the "Detroit vs London" school of testing. We don't want to test that Kafka hex connector works but that application as a whole work. We have unit tests, and they are important. But again, you can test your application in many ways so no point in starting a holly war about it. I accept Aleksei's link to a bug as depending on internal client call is IMHO an oversight.

Comment: @komfitura so which part of the ktor framework is your kafka consumer using other than it shares a main function? But l am definately not looking for any testing religious war :) if this is how you want to test that your kafka consumer is polling for messages and handling them the  go ahead.

Comment: we probably have a bit too extensive testing solution. Still, we decided to go with (what we call) integration tests that test Ktor together with Kafka (real one or recently Kafka-provided mock library for streams/consumers/producers), so everything, until external interactions like API (mocked by Wiremock or Mockk). We do not test Ktor per se. We test that the application is correctly wired and works as expected or crashes as expected. Testing only Kafka layer is fine but doesn't prove the app works as expected - and yes, we also have a layer of dockerized e2e tests, but we test less ther